# Adhesive for FR-4 substrate

Tags: antenna, pcb-antenna

I would to know what sort of adhesive I can use to stick 3 FR-4 PCB's together?

Back to back. These PCB's measure at 8 by 8 cm. With a single FR-4 substrate thickness at 1.6mm.

The reason for sticking them together is I want to make an antenna's substrate 4.8mm high and I only have 1.6mm PCB's available.

My only option is to get it done via my university which has minimal equipment. Basically what they said is they will cut the substrate to size and the sticking is your problem so I assume they do not have the resources.

Comment: Most epoxies would work. FR4 is basically fiberglass set in epoxy . It may be hard to get equal penetration and monitor curing of a large board. Confromal epoxy for PCB or soldermask repair would work well. Have you asked your PCB supplier if they would do a 4.8mm stackup? It's not unheard of.

Comment: Is this low loss tangent FR4? or < 1GHz

Comment: You could just buy fiberglass plate that thick. It won't have copper on it though.

Comment: Hi Tony it is less than 1GHz my resonant frequency is 915 Mhz. Bare in mind I haven't used this substrate before so I have no experience with it

Comment: @crasic I am getting it done by my university but they don't have the resources to do a stackup

Comment: Do you have a budget? A custom panel will be a few dollars, but not more than $1000

Comment: @crasic A 100 x 100 mm board with 4.8mm stackup (2-layer) is $125 USD for 5 pieces from a typical China PCB maker.

Comment: If you're at a US university and have access to a milling machine or lithography setup you should get sample material from Rogers and use that to fab your antenna.

Comment: @SpheronPefhany I didn't make an assumption on panel size or turnaround so it is just a max order of magnitude. Certainly if you are willing to wait and compromise quality it can be very cheap . If it's unetched you can get directly from substrate supplier

Comment: @crasic I do not necessarily have a budget but my ONLY option is too get it done at my University which is in South Africa.

Comment: @Captainj2001 My only option is to get it done via my university which has minimal equipment. Basically what they said is they will cut the substrate to size and the sticking is your problem so I assume they do not have the resources.

Comment: Can you change to problem slightly so that you have the two boards separated by an air gap and adjust the spacing between them? You might then just be able to get away with using nylon spacers and the standard local process for the boards.

Comment: Is it possible to tick a comment as an answer? Can someone assist?